# Remove module.exports declarations when transpiling with babel

Tags: node.js, babeljs

Is there a way to remove module.exports declarations when transpiling with Babel? I am using module.exports for testing (Jest) but I don't want those exports to make it to the production files.

For example if I have the following js file that I want to transpile using Babel:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

How can I remove the `module.exports = sum;` from the transpiled version?

Comment: Your example file don't need transportation it doesn't use any es6+ syntax

Comment: That is not the point. I wasn't asking if I should transpile that or not. That is just an example, not the actual code.

Comment: I mean from your description it's not obvious that you want a) transform your ES6+ code down to ES5 ***OR*** b) convert your already transformed ES5 code partially back to ES6

Comment: since the host environment (browser/node) is moving fast is in between ES5-6

Comment: I am transforming ES6 to ES5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I used gulp as a solution:
in your gulpfile.babel.js add a filter for removing whatever you want from your js file using a regex pattern like this:

```
    const compiledDir = './src/compiled';
// Lines that you want to remove in this case you have two.
    const filters = [
      /^"use strict";/,
      /^module.exports = parseSiteSectionName;/
    ];

// then add a task into the same file that uses the filter:

    gulp.task('build-sum', () => {
      let buildResult = browserify({ debug: false })
        .transform(babelify)
        .require(`./src/sum.js`, { entry: true })
        .bundle()
        .on('error', (err) => { console.log('Error: ' + err.message); })
        .pipe(source('sum.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(template({ env }))
        // Remove lines that are in your filter
        .pipe(removeLines({ filters: filters }));
    

      buildResult = buildResult
        .pipe(jsEscape({
          omitDelimiters: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(compiledDir));
    
      return buildResult;
    });
```